# How can I track the progress / read the output file of an ongoing calculation in GAMESS-LIBCCHEM from NVIDIA?

Tags: computational-chemistry

That is my question:

- How can I track the progress / read the output file of an ongoing calculation in GAMESS-LIBCCHEM from NVIDIA?

The steps I have followed are in:

1. https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/gpu-accelerated-applications/gamess/

In there, there is a command line:

```
nvidia-docker run -v $(pwd):/results --rm nvcr.io/hpc/gamess:17.09-r2-libcchem -c "cd /workspace/examples && rungms cc-h2co.inp"
```

But, that command line print an output file only when the calculation has finished.

I want to read the output while the calculation is running and I do not know how.

I am running it on my laptop: i7 + geforce 940m + 12 gb of ram

Comment: You generally have much better luck with such highly specialized questions, if you contact either the developers themselves (nvidia-docker) or the user community.

Comment: This seems to relate to a specific program or programming issue, rather than an underlying chemical issue

Comment: Of course, you could always bring this up at [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table). In matters pertaining to computational chem, I recommend asking Mod. @Martin about it ;-)